# Page title utf-8 encoding not working

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, title

I have a problem with some serbian letters showing in page title (they look like this %C5%A1). I added `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` on top of my page in first line and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` above the title tag. Also my file that generates title is utf-8 encoded. Any idea why it still doesnt show properly?

Comment: Is your file saved as UTF-8 itself also?

Comment: If it looks like "%C5%A1" then you probably got it from unparsed urlencoded string... this is not valid html entity, so it will stay like this no matter what. Try using `urldecode` PHP function on it.

Comment: Where did u get this title from? From GET / POST ? Something did urlencoded it, so the easiest way would be just NOT to do that.

Comment: @FlashThunder it worked with urldecode! Thank u very much. U want to put answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it looks like "%C5%A1" then you probably got it from unparsed urlencoded string... this is not valid html entity, so it will stay like this no matter what. Try using `urldecode` PHP function on it.